# DisplayPort to HDMI Audio work for Linux Ubuntu but not Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, displayport

My desktop Dell OptiPlex XE2, with Intel HD Graphic 4600 display card is able to produce sound/audio via DisplayPort to HDMI cable in Linux Ubuntu, but not Windows 10. Below is screenshot in Ubuntu where this OS is able to show HDMI / DisplayPort as sound output.

[image]

At Windows 10, even after update to the latest driver, there is no Intel Display Audio in Device Manager.

Could someone help on this? Any generic driver (like Ubuntu) that I can use? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 the Intel Display Audio does not appear as it's own device. Instead the device connected **through** the HDMI port capable of audio will appear as the audio device **if connected** and properly installed.

[Screenshot of HDMI/DP displays that have an audio hub attached connected and disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZEjf.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a faulty cable. Somehow in Linux, this cable has no issue. Maybe Linux is able to ignore faulty signaling. After changing to a new working cable, Windows 10 can produce sound without issue.